# Unsupported file ion Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, github

My friend and I are making a simple game that runs in a window. I already started on it, and I am using Visual Studio Community 2015, yet my friend has a Mac, so he cannot use the same IDE that I am using. I am using a windows form, but the code for it is normal C++ code, however when my friend tries to clone the repository, it says that it is an unsupported file. Does anyone know who this is? Or any IDE's for Mac that can run this code?

```
#pragma once

namespace TextRPG {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for UserInterface
/// </summary>
public ref class UserInterface : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    UserInterface(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~UserInterface()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
public: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox1;
protected:
public: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox2;
public: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  option1;
public: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  option2;
public: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  option3;
public: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  option4;
public: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  startGame;
public: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  saveGame;

public:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->pictureBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->pictureBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->option1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->option2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->option3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->option4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->startGame = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->saveGame = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox1))->BeginInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox2))->BeginInit();
        // 
        // pictureBox2
        // 
        this->pictureBox2->ImageLocation = L"C:\\Users\\sylva\\Source\\Repos\\Text-RPG\\Mohammed_Background Scenery.PNG";
        this->pictureBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 0);
        this->pictureBox2->Name = L"pictureBox2";
        this->pictureBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(870, 627);
        this->pictureBox2->SizeMode = System::Windows::Forms::PictureBoxSizeMode::AutoSize;
        this->pictureBox2->TabIndex = 1;
        this->pictureBox2->TabStop = false;
        this->pictureBox2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &UserInterface::pictureBox2_Click);
        // 
        // option1
        // 
        this->option1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(61, 418);
        this->option1->Name = L"option1";
        this->option1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(256, 62);
        this->option1->TabIndex = 2;
        this->option1->Text = L"option1";
        this->option1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->option1->Visible = false;
        // 
        // option2
        // 
        this->option2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(434, 418);
        this->option2->Name = L"option2";
        this->option2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(256, 62);
        this->option2->TabIndex = 3;
        this->option2->Text = L"option2";
        this->option2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->option2->Visible = false;
        // 
        // option3
        // 
        this->option3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(61, 516);
        this->option3->Name = L"option3";
        this->option3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(256, 62);
        this->option3->TabIndex = 4;
        this->option3->Text = L"option3";
        this->option3->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->option3->Visible = false;
        // 
        // option4
        // 
        this->option4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(434, 516);
        this->option4->Name = L"option4";
        this->option4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(256, 62);
        this->option4->TabIndex = 5;
        this->option4->Text = L"option4";
        this->option4->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->option4->Visible = false;
        // 
        // startGame
        // 
        this->startGame->Location = System::Drawing::Point(276, 317);
        this->startGame->Name = L"startGame";
        this->startGame->Size = System::Drawing::Size(195, 66);
        this->startGame->TabIndex = 6;
        this->startGame->Text = L"Start Game";
        this->startGame->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->startGame->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &UserInterface::startGame_Click);
        // 
        // saveGame
        // 
        this->saveGame->Location = System::Drawing::Point(13, 13);
        this->saveGame->Name = L"saveGame";
        this->saveGame->Size = System::Drawing::Size(114, 37);
        this->saveGame->TabIndex = 7;
        this->saveGame->Text = L"Save Game";
        this->saveGame->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->saveGame->Visible = false;
        // 
        // UserInterface
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(763, 590);
        this->Controls->Add(this->saveGame);
        this->Controls->Add(this->startGame);
        this->Controls->Add(this->option4);
        this->Controls->Add(this->option3);
        this->Controls->Add(this->option2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->option1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox1);
        this->Name = L"UserInterface";
        this->Text = L"UserInterface";
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox1))->EndInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox2))->EndInit();
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
#pragma endregion
public: System::Void pictureBox2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
}
public: System::Void startGame_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    option1->Visible = true;
    option2->Visible = true;
    option3->Visible = true;
    option4->Visible = true;
    saveGame->Visible = true;
    startGame->Visible = false;
}
};
}
```

Comment: " the code for it is normal C++ code" - what you posted is NOT normal C++ code. Looks like managed C++ for .NET platform.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two ways for fixing this. Your friend can install virtual machine and run VS 2015 on this machine. The second way is CLion by Jetbrains, it is one of the cool IDE s for C++ developers and it is available both for windows and Mac maybe you can use it.